# Comparing analytical and empirical moments of pareto distribution

Tags: python, comparison, simulation, analytical

Below I used the nympy generated draws to compare the empirical moments of Pareto distribution with analytical ones (I used the following link for the formulas of mean, variance, skewness and excess kurtosis, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution). Obtained results for mean and variance are similar, however the results for skewness and kurtosis are very different. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you beforehand

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import skew
from scipy.stats import kurtosis
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x_m = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
alpha = [5, 6, 7, 8]

#drawing samples from distribution

for a, x in zip(alpha, x_m):
    print (a, x)
data = (np.random.default_rng().pareto(a, 10000000)+1) * x
mean = np.mean(data) 
var = np.var(data) 
skew = skew(data) 
kurt = kurtosis(data)

#Analytical estimation

for a, x in zip(alpha, x_m):
    a_mean = (a*x)/(a-1)
    a_var = (a*x**2)/((a-1)**2*(a-2))
    a_skew = (2*(1+a)/(a-3))*(np.sqrt(a-2/a))
    a_kurt = (6*(a**3+a**2-6*a-2))/(a*(a-3)*(a-4))
    
#Table

header = ['Moments', 'Simulated', 'Analytical']
Moments = ['Mean', 'Variance', 'Skewness', 'Excess Kurtosis']
Simulated = [round(mean,4), round(var,4), round(skew,4), round(kurt,4)]
Analytical = [round(a_mean,4), round(a_var,4), round(a_skew,4), round(a_kurt,4)]
table = PrettyTable()

table.add_column(header[0], Moments)
table.add_column(header[1], Simulated)
table.add_column(header[2], Analytical)
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

its a small typo in the analytical skewness line:

```
a_skew = (2*(1+a)/(a-3))*(np.sqrt(a-2/a))
```

should be

```
a_skew = (2*(1+a)/(a-3))*(np.sqrt((a-2)/a))
```

The Kurtosis is correct with a sufficiently large sample.

Comment: Thank you, I got it